# (Invalid privacy policy url) Getting rejection from google play store?

Tags: flutter, privacy-policy

[image]

In above image, There are some google policy requirement. My app policy fulfill with all policy requirement. But still I'm getting rejection with same reason.

- I have also attached privacy in store lising and in my application.

Comment: Add privacy policy in App Description

Comment: Added and still getting rejection for same reason

Comment: In the app, content section Privacy Policy added?

Comment: Yes. I have added policy url in app content and also attached in application on login and signup page. Also added delete account feature as per thier latest google policy. but still getting rejection for invalid privacy policy url.

Comment: Then need to check all info.

Comment: Yes. We updated our content thrice. but getting same reason for rejection. " invalid privacy policy url" Is that any thing wrong with url ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried many times to reupload my apk with different policy content. But nothing changed. My app got approval once I changed privacy policy url and not the content.

Comment: Thanks a lot. We have been trying that thing for a long.

Answer (score 0):

Your Privacy Policy URL must be non-editable by users and accessible (i.e. no PDFs, plain HTML is best).

You need to add it in the app store listing page and within the app screens (i.e. Login, Signup).

Examples:

[image]
[image]

Comment: My policy is non-editable

Comment: What's the URL?

Comment: https://www.groceryboo.com/privacy/

Comment: Please tell me if anything is missing

Comment: If the Privacy Policy URL is OK (not 404), then the issue may be around the contents of Privacy Policy: missing data retention & data deletion provisions, etc. It's best to sync with the permissions your app requires.